# Why do I see only code on my iPhone App?

Tags: bug, ios-app

Often I'm on MSE via my iPhone, where the math in comments only was shown as code, but in posts it was "compiled" normally so I didn't bother too much. But suddenly a few weeks ago, the math was shown only in code even in the posts, which makes rather difficult to read them. What is going on? Is this problem known, do you have this problem too? How to fix it? I'm not sure if this is the right side to post this question, thanks for indicating if you think I should post it elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?